# Link and Style tag get XHTML warning in cshtml

Tags: css, razor

I tried using

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Extras.css")" 
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

but got a warning

```
Validation (XHTML 1.0 Transitional): Element 'link' cannot be 
nested within element 'link'.
```

So I tried

```
<style></style>
```

and got a very similar warning

```
"Validation (XHTML 1.0 Transitional): Element 'style' cannot be 
nested within element 'style'."
```

How can I conform to this validation?

Comment: @alirizaadiyahsi - that link does provide a good explanation about why this happens. I will post an answer which shows how to dynamically append the link tag to the head in a few minutes.

Comment: Not sure if this will help with the warning, but you have a quote problem in your first example. You can't put quotes in a quoted attribute value.

Comment: @MrLister - Thank you for the suggestion, but the razor engine will actually compile that into a string which will sit inside the outside quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Alirizaadiyahsi linked in a comment (although it has since been removed) the cause of this warning is that `<link>` and `<style>` tags may only go in the head of the document.

This is an issue for me because I want to have custom styles for certain areas in my asp.net mvc 3 site. To solve the problem, I did this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var x = document.createElement("link");
 x.setAttribute("href",'@(Url.Content("~/Content/Extras.css"))');
 x.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
 x.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
 $('head')[0].appendChild(x);
</script>
```